# API call returning different results based on whitespace encoding (%2520 vs. %20)

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, yql

I just switched from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking.

My app allows a user to enter a search term, and then I make an api call to my server (rails) to retrieve a list of relevant objects to display on the phone. Simple enough.

**Too Long, Won't Read**

With the ASI library, the search term sent to the server would be something like `st%20helena`. Now, with the AFNetworking, my search term sent to the server is `st%2520helena`. Oddly enough, this is actually making a difference. With `%20`, I receive no results. With `%2520`, I receive the results I was expecting.

My question is, **why does this make a difference**? I know that `%2520` is an encoded '%' + 20, which equals a whitespace character, which in my mind should be identical to passing `%20`.

**Details**

Before, I was simply appending the search term to the URL after first encoding it:

```
NSString *encoded = [@"st helena" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/?=%@, encoded];
```

Now, with AFNetworking, I'm passing an NSDictionary to the `parameters` argument of `AFHTTPClient#getPath`.

```
NSString *encoded = [@"st helena" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTR8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"q" : encoded };
[[myClient sharedClient] getPath:@"" parameters:dict ...]
```

Since AFNetworking encodes items in the dictionary, my search string is being double encoded, which is why the % of '%20' is being converted into '%25'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why does this make a difference? I know that `%2520` is an encoded '%' + 20, which equals a whitespace character, which in my mind should be identical to passing `%20`.

No, they aren't identical.  The parsing code isn't supposed to just keep decoding over and over again until there aren't any more percent signs left.  If that were the case, it would be impossible to transmit the actual percent character.  It's only supposed to decode it once.  This means that if `%2520` goes over the wire, it is decoded into the data `%20` and processing stops there.  If `%20` goes over the wire, it is decoded once into a space.  The decoding is only supposed to happen once.  If your web service is treating `%2520` as a space, then it has a double-decoding bug.

Comment: Actually a single decoding pass of `%25%20` gives `% ` while a double decoding pass on `%25%20` has an unspecified result. On the other hand a single decoding pass of `%2520` gives `%20` while a double decoding pass on `%2520` is perfectly valid and gives a space.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.  I meant `%2520` like in the question.  The latter double decoding pass is valid in the sense that it has a defined result, but incorrect in the sense that you shouldn't be double decoding in the first place.

Comment: I ended up coming to the same conclusion and was in the middle of writing an answer of how this problem confused YQL and Sphinx, but your answer is more general and will probably be more useful to future readers. Thanks!